# Unnecessary CSSs and optimization

Tags: html, css, optimization, webkit

Does including of unnecessary CSSs slow down a browser (Chromium, Mobile Safari)?

I mean,

```
function insert_style_sheet()
{
    include "style_sheet.tpl";
}
```

in every php file. The template file style_sheet.tpl is the following:

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="css/controls.css">
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="css/whatever.css">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, and you can try measuring the differences with a performance analyzer like YSlow. An extra stylesheet or two may have a negligible speed effect, depending on how big it is. Essentially, more stylesheets adds this to the pipeline:

- More CSS rules that the browser has to check each element against
- More HTTP round trips to grab the CSS file (reducing the number of HTTP calls is of great importance, look into combining your stylesheets)
- More bytes that have to be downloaded

As Paul Irish [recently tweeted](https://twitter.com/#!/paul_irish/status/143077300441853952), "When you're optimizing performance of your site/app, your priorities are 1. Network connections 2. DOM access 3. Javascript optimizations."

Comment: What's the general rule on CSSs then? Should I merge all CSS always to decrease network connection count?

Comment: It depends. Merging CSS is usually a very good idea, and minimizing is always a good idea. The only downside to merging CSS is some pages might not need most of the CSS rules, but the user would still have to download the full merged stylesheet. If you have lots of unique pages with page specific CSS, and lots of individual CSS files, then merging may create unnecessary bloat for other pages.

Answer (score 3):

It can definitely slow your site down. It's really best to reduce the # of css files by combining them when possible. It also depends on how much css is in each one of those files and wether or not they're bloated.

Answer (score 3):

Page load time is affected by:

1. Number of .css files downloaded
2. Size of .css files downloaded

Page performance: (best seen when scrolling or resizing browser windows)

1. Number of selectors the browser has to look for.
2. Number of properties on each selector

So... Combine files, remove unused css properties and selectors. Compress your css, but save an uncompressed version so you can edit in semantics, and then compress and save it.

That's how I work with CSS. Hope it's helpful to you!